# Analysis of experimental data with asymmetric design

Tags: categorical-data, experiment-design, missing-data

What is the best way to analyse experimental data in which there aren't data points for all levels of each of the factors? Here is an example (article forms in German) in order to illustrate the issue:

Factor A has two levels (definite, indefinite).

Factor B has three levels (masculine, feminine, neuter) at level "definite" of Factor A but only two levels (masculine/neuter, feminine) at level "indefinite" of Factor A.

So not only are there an inconsistent number of levels of Factor B, but when Factor B only has two levels (masculine/neuter, feminine), it is actually due to two levels collapsing into one. The premise of the research requires that Factor A and Factor B be directly compared at all levels.

The dependent variable is ratings from a 4-point Likert scale. Both Factor A and Factor B are within-subjects variables, and there is also a Group variable which is between-subjects.